# Implicit and explicit casting

Tags: c, casting

Using:

```
float return1(void);

int  main()
{ 
      int    x;
      x   =   (float)return1();
      printf("%f",x);
      return 0;
}

float return1()
{
       return 1;
}`
```

Why is the output `-0.000000`?

Shouldn't `x` be implicitly cast to a `float` and print `1.000000`?

Comment: Did you mean to use `printf("%d",x);` or to cast x within the printf?

Comment: [tag:c] or [tag:c++], there is a big difference in this between the two. Although your code is very wrong in both, in c++ you would `static_cast<float>()`.

Comment: Okay, short and quick answer is make x a float. Boom. Problem solved.

Comment: If you call a donkey "horse", does it become a horse?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because more stupid, known to be stupid but an explanation asked for anyway.    This subclass is 'stupid casting'.  Usefulness to future users/visitors: zero or negative.

Comment: Dude this question is for me and i'll be a good program only if i ask stupid questions :)

Comment: Casting is a problem for noobs, you should know. Right? Easy question. Yes. But needed for some.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't x be implicitly cast to a float and print 1.000000?

No, it shouldn't because the compiler may not know what `printf` does or which format will be used to print `x`.

`x` has type `int`, so `%d` should be used instead of `%f` to print it.

Answer (score 2):

*Why is the output -0.000000?*

because of

```
    printf("%f",x);
```

and x is int,  if you want 1.00:, do

```
    printf("%f", (double) x);
```

or better change it to:

```
    printf("%i", x);
```

Answer (score 2):

`printf` doesn't cast and interpret object according to the flag given in format string (`%f` currently).

depending of what you want

```
printf("%d", x);
```

or

```
printf("%f", (float)x);
```

or in C++:

```
std::cout << x; // or float(x)
```

Comment: `printf("%f", float(x));` isn't valid C.

Answer (score 1):

No need to cast `return1()` to `float`; your `x` is integer and you want to format it to `float` in `printf`

```
float return1(void);

int main(void)
{
    int x;

    x = return1();
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}

float return1()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `t_main`?

Comment: @Alter Mann I used VS2010 for testing and I created a Console App and thus VS2010 created a console app with int _tmain function as input function. I agree _tmain that does not exist in C ++ and main does. _tmain is a Microsoft extension.

Comment: @Varun Saproo This function returns1() returns a float , then you do not need to cast to float [x = (float) back 1 ()].
Furthermore x is integer (even if it is filled with a float). you pass an integer to printf ("% f", x) and ask formatting as a float.

solution : x must be either a float or you format x as integer.  For that, you put printf ("% d", x). sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't. The compiler does generally not check the correspondence between the format string and the arguments you provide. In your case, it would be able to do so, but what if someone passes a string variable as format string? That is the reason for most compilers not checking the correspondence.